# Menubar does not appear in tkinter when configured

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object, tkinter

I am creating an tkinter app. For now I just want to get a very basic menubar to work, with a file section, and an exit button in the sub menu. Here is my object oriented code, which may be where I am going wrong:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init_(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.filemenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)
        self.config(menu=self.menubar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

However, this only creates a blank tkinter window. This usually works for me when I use procedural programming so I think I am doing something wrong with OOP. I am trying to say self.config() as root.config(), but this does not work.

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging, such as verifying that `__init_` is running? Hint: it's not. It should be `__init__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 big issues there. The first is that you misspelled `__init__`, so none of your custom code is being run. The second is that you need to apply the menu to the root window, aka self.master (default name) or self.parent (your name). Try like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.filemenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)
        self.master.config(menu=self.menubar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('200x200') # remove once you've added window content
    win = MainApplication(root)
    win.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

I also moved you to a python3 inheritance style, and defined a size so that you actually see something.